# Visual Studio Sql Server не распознает колонку как int

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, linq

У меня не получается сравнить '>' `tP.productPrice` из-за ошибки что этот оператор не может сравнить типы string и int. Когда я навожу на ошибку, visual studio читает ее как string. Но в моей базе данных productPrice это int. 
[image: Ошибка]

```
  db = new DataClasses1DataContext();
                var priceProducts = 
                        from tP in db.Products
                        where tP.productPrice > 0 && tP.productPrice<100
```

Определение таблицы:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Проблема в методе `DataClasses1DataContext()` ?

Comment: добавьте схему таблицы и способ, которым вы сгенерировали контекст, в вопрос.

Comment: Очевидно, что в контексте это свойство задано у вас как `string`. Какой подход используете: CodeFirst, DatabaseFirst?

Answer (score -1):

Проблема в том что вы запрашиваете значение из базы в формате String и поле у вас [image: Поле]   вот так будет сравнивать  `< Convert.ToInt32(tp.productprice)`

Comment: Неужели нельзя без скриншота обойтись? Публиковать код как текст. / `Convert.ToInt32` - ну вот зачем? Нужно само поле в контексте объявить как `int`.